# Is there a way to Export Product Variations from WooCommerce and into a '.csv'/Excel file?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a WordPress website, with WooCommerce functionality.

I would like to provide the client with a full breakdown of all the product variations that are currently on the website.  For 1 product alone, there are over 500 Product Variations.  Rather than type all these up manually, is there not a way I could export these into a .csv or Excel file etc?

I have looked on the internet and can see a few Plugins but would rather try and figure this out without a Plugin.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can see the [simplest plugin](https://www.webtoffee.com/product/product-import-export-woocommerce/) for doing this here.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Mujeebu Rahman.  Is there not a way to do this without a Plugin or would this require a lot of work which would be outside the scope a single SO Question?

Comment: @Craig : It can be done but needs lot of coding as a variable product is having lot of different properties like category, tags,images...etc

Comment: Ok, no worries.  Thanks for this insight.

Comment: I hate the fact that the answer links to a paid product. And I need that paid product to do the thing in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this myself, quick findings:

- the built-in WooCommerce product exporter doesn't export the variations alongside simple products
- Store Exporter Deluxe doesn't either
- WP All Export Pro does the job
- [Product Import Export Plugin For WooCommerce](https://www.webtoffee.com/product/product-import-export-woocommerce/) by WebToffee looks promising, but I haven't tried it yet.