# WordPress products data to export to Excel file

Tags: php, wordpress, product, export-to-excel

Can somebody lead me on the way or give some piece of code to export Wordpress products to Excel or something like this? Thank you a lot. I'm just starting coding plugins like this so trying to find now here some answers if not just lead me on the way thank you guys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to Export Product Variations from WooCommerce and into a '.csv'/Excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142817/is-there-a-way-to-export-product-variations-from-woocommerce-and-into-a-csv-e)

Answer (score 1):

```
<h4>There is a [sample-data] file in the WooCommerce plugin in which you will find the product data.</h>
```

**There is a [sample-data] file in the WooCommerce plugin in which you will find the product data.**